# How to hide a Null text when a column is empty in a Share Point 2013 List?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have a Share Point list and, in some cases, some of the columns are empty; in this case the text null is shown. I need null to disappear whenever a column is empty. This is the code I have originally.

```
var buildModal = function(items) {
var modalContent = $('#modalContent');

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

var modalContentCard = '<div class="modal fade" id=basicExample'+items[i].ID+'  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"  role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><strong>' + items[i].Title +
'</strong></h5><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div><div class="modal-body"><h5>Personal:</h5><p><strong>A dream I have is to:</strong> '+ items[i].Dream +'</p><p><strong>You would be surprised to learn that I:</strong>'+ items[i].Learn +'</p><p><strong>My motto is:</strong>'+ items[i].Motto +
'</p><p><strong>The mission of our agency is:</strong>'+ items[i].Mission +'</p><hr><h5>Our current priorities are:</h5><p>'+ items[i].Priorities +'</p><h5>Our biggest accomplishments in the past year include:</h5><p>'+ items[i].Accomplishments +'</p><div class="agency"><h5>One thing you did not know about our agency is:</h5><p>'+ items[i].Agency+'</p></div><div class="mt-3 mb-3"><a href="'+ items[i].Link.Url +'" target="_blank">'+ items[i].Website +'</a></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div></div></div></div>';
modalContent.prepend(modalContentCard);
}

});

};
```

I tried adding this code with no results

```
var empty = $('p');
console.log(empty);

$.each(empty, function(element) {
       var text = element.innerHTML;    
  if (text === " ") {
    text.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <h5>Personal:</h5>
  <p><strong>A dream I have is to:</strong> </p>
  <div class="ExternalClass44F41EEF57F6405EBDCDF166AAE64839">
    <p>Travel the world, starting with a trip around the US in an RV!&nbsp;<br></p>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <p><strong>You would be surprised to learn that I:</strong></p>
  <div class="ExternalClass609F53F5A4794345A04360BEA3C8A50F">
    <p>Was extremely shy as a child.</p>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <p><strong>My motto is:</strong>null</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Wherever you concat your text, replace `yourVariable` with `(yourVariable || '')`

Comment: @ayrton thanks for the reply that works perfectly. What if I want to hide this completely
`<p><strong>My motto is:</strong>null</p>` meaning not even My motto to show?

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply replace the "null" text with empty text, go to your concats and replace `yourVariable` with `(yourVariable || '')`.

If you wish to completely hide elements where the text is null, you should build them individually and wrap them in `if` blocks. For example, to hide your `<p>` element:

```
var modalContent = ...

if(items[i].Motto) {
    modalContent += "<p><strong>My motto is:</strong>"+ items[i].Motto +
"</p>";
}
```

If you with to check only for `null`, add `!== null` in your `if`.

**PS:** Also note that using strings might not be the best way to create your HTML elements. You should probably use `createElement` and similars.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement